# Where can I catch each of the fish required to earn the 'Pandarian Angler' achievement?

Tags: achievements, world-of-warcraft

On the island of Pandaria, there is a variety of aquatic life forms and an achievement to capture them all. These fish are used in a variety of recipes for cooking and other things, in addition to contributing towards Zen Master Fishing.

The new fish are:

- Emperor Salmon
- Giant Mantis Shrimp
- Jade Lungfish
- Krasarang Paddlefish
- Redbelly Mandarin
- Spinefish Alpha
- Flying Tiger Gourami
- Golden Carp
- Jewel Danio
- Mimic Octopus
- Reef Octopus
- Tiger Gourami

Some of these fish don't appear to have pools that spawn as far as I can tell, and I have caught Golden Carp from Reef Octopus pools.

Where can I find each of these fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are all locations for catching them:**

[**Emperor Salmon**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/emperor_salmon.html)

Krasarang Wilds, Townlong Steppes (Inland), Vale of Eternal Blossoms, Valley of the Four Winds

[**Giant Mantis Shrimp**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/giant_mantis_shrimp.html)

Dread Wastes (Coastal), The Jade Forest (Coastal), Krasarang Wilds, Kun-Lai Summit (Coastal), Townlong Steppes (Coastal), Valley of the Four Winds

[**Jade Lungfish**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/jade_lungfish.html)

The Jade Forest (Inland)

[**Krasarang Paddlefish**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/krasarang_paddlefish.html)

Krasarang Wilds (Inland), Valley of the Four Winds (Inland) , Vale of Eternal Blossoms (Inland)

[**Redbelly Mandarin**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/redbelly_mandarin.html)

The Jade Forest (Inland), Townlong Steppes (Inland), Vale of Eternal Blossoms (Inland)

[**Spinefish Alpha**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/spinefish_alpha.html)

Dread Wastes (Inland), The Jade Forest (Widow's Wail), Kun-Lai Summit (Sha-Touched)

[**Flying Tiger Gourami**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/flying_tiger_gourami.html)

The Jade Forest (Inland) , Krasarang Wilds, Valley of the Four Winds, Townlong Steppes (Inland), Kun-Lai Summit (Inland), The Veiled Stair, Vale of Eternal Blossoms

[**Golden Carp**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/golden_carp.html)

Kun-Lai Summit (Inland), The Veiled Stair, The Jade Forest (Inland), Krasarang Wilds, Valley of the Four Winds, Townlong Steppes (Inland), Vale of Eternal Blossoms, Dread Wastes (Coastal), The Jade Forest (Coastal), Krasarang Wilds, Kun-Lai Summit (Coastal), Townlong Steppes (Coastal), Valley of the Four Winds, Dread Wastes (Inland), The Jade Forest (Widow's Wail), Kun-Lai Summit (Sha-Touched)

[**Jewel Danio**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/jewel_danio.html)

Vale of Eternal Blossoms (Inland)

[**Mimic Octopus**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/mimic_octopus.html)

Dread Wastes (Coastal), The Jade Forest (Coastal), Krasarang Wilds, Kun-Lai Summit (Coastal), Townlong Steppes (Coastal), Valley of the Four Winds

[**Reef Octopus**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/reef_octopus.html)

Dread Wastes (Coastal), The Jade Forest (Coastal), Krasarang Wilds, Kun-Lai Summit (Coastal), Townlong Steppes (Coastal), Valley of the Four Winds

[**Tiger Gourami**](http://www.elsanglin.com/fish/tiger_gourami.html)

Kun-Lai Summit (Inland), The Veiled Stair

====================

**Source:** [Elsanglin](http://www.elsanglin.com/mop_catches.html)